# How to correctly open, process and print a file in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a file which has IBM852 encoding. I can confirm it when opening it in my texteditor with that encoding.

I want to open that file, write it in another `.rtf` text file and then print it. I tried like this, but always get an error:

> File "print_rawpcl.py", line 38, in     d.write(raw_data) 
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1250.py", line 19, in encode
>   return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
>   nicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position
>   522-601: character maps to *undefined*

What would be the correct way to take this file, rewrite it in another file and send it to a printer via ShellExecute?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import time
import win32api
import win32print
import tempfile


my_encoding = "cp852"

# If there is command line argument, the first one is our file_to_print
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    file_to_print = sys.argv[1]
else:
    print("No input file")
    sys.exit()

try:
    with open(file_to_print, "r", encoding=my_encoding) as f:
        raw_data = f.read()
    filename = tempfile.mktemp(".rtf")
    with open(filename, "w") as d:
        d.write(raw_data)
        win32api.ShellExecute(
          0,
          "print",
          filename,
          '/d:"%s"' % win32print.GetDefaultPrinter(),
          ".",
          0
        )
except OSError as e:
    print("Failed: {}".format(e))

print("Script ended. Everything OK!")
time.sleep(2)
```

I am copying this to rtf so that Windows print it with WordPad, because when printing from Notepad I get file title and page number which I don't won't.